# Spring Security и авторизация через OAuth2 (Google) без Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth2

Не могли бы вы посоветовать дельные статьи по прикручиванию гуглоавторизации? Дело в том, что везде все пишется только со Spring Boot, что не очень помогает разбору с нуля, так сказать. Пробовал использовать то, что есть в официальных доках, но оно выдает ошибку, о которой вообще информации ноль (могу рассказать поподробнее, если интересно), задавал по ней вопрос на английском стаковерфлоу - уже месяц без ответа.

По поводу ошибки.

- Заходим на localhost:8080, появляется Login with OAuth 2.0 и список провайдеров.
- Выбираем, например, Google (не существенно, результат один и тот же), редиректит на гугловскую страницу ввода логина и пароля, вводим их.
- Редиректит на localhost:8080/login?error c сообщением:

  ```
  [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: Error while extracting response for type [class org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponse] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: An error occurred reading the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: null; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
  ```

Вот код:

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .oauth2Login();
    }   

    @Bean   
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {        
        List<ClientRegistration> clientRegistrations = new ArrayList<ClientRegistration>();     
        clientRegistrations.add(CommonOAuth2Provider.GOOGLE.getBuilder("google").clientId("id").clientSecret("secret").build());
        clientRegistrations.add(CommonOAuth2Provider.FACEBOOK.getBuilder("facebook").clientId("id").clientSecret("secret").build());            
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrations);               
    }   

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository(OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        return new AuthenticatedPrincipalOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository(authorizedClientService);
    }

}
```

---

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer { }
```

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.solarward.auth")
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer, ApplicationContextAware  {   

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;  

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {      
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");        
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);        
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);       
        return templateResolver;        
    }   

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {      
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());     
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer  {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {       
        return null;        
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {        
        return new Class[] { WebConfiguration.class };      
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {       
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

Comment: Без примеров кода сложно вам что-то ответить. Лично у меня с первого раза получилось прикрутить. Правда на `boot` и авторизация с андроид-приложения стартует. У вас не ясно - таков сценарий или вы про сайт. В общем нужны горы подробностей о коде и ошибках в нём.

Comment: Да вот с boot как раз работает без проблем. Код добавил. Об ошибке подробностей особо и нет, в логах тот же текст.

Comment: Угу... К сожалению, так я реализовывать не пробовал. Единственный совет могу дать - запустить в дебаг режиме и пытаться найти в исходниках спринга где именно NPE получается. Скорее всего надо какие-то ещё зависимости добавить в настройки авторизации.

Comment: Все верно, как раз принялся перебирать зависимости из boot-версии и - о чудо! - заработало. Jackson нужно было добавить всего-то.

Answer (score 1):

Решено! Всего-то не хватало зависимостей Jackson.